# How to run binded service method in AsyncTask android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-service

Hi i've got a problem I want to use a Running service method in my AsyncTask.

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

    boolean bBindedBluetooth;
    static BTService Bluetooth;

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
      super.onStart();  
      new ActivityStarter().execute("");};@Override
    protected void onStop() { super.onStop(); unbindMyService("onStop"); };  
    @Override
    protected void onPause(){ super.onPause(); unbindMyService("onPause"); };
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() { super.onDestroy(); unbindMyService("onDestroy"); }; 


    ...

    private class ActivityStarter extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try{
                Intent btIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, BTService.class);
                bindService(btIntent, scConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
                //Bluetooth.initService();
                //Bluetooth.StartBluetoothConnection(); 

            } catch (Exception e){
                Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Intent MainActivityIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            SplashActivity.this.startActivity(MainActivityIntent);
            SplashActivity.this.finish();
        }

    }           


    private void unbindMyService(String methodNameForLog){
        try{
              if(bBindedBluetooth){
                  unbindService(scConnection);
                  bBindedBluetooth = false;
              }
          }catch(Exception e){
              Log.e( this.getClass().getSimpleName(), methodNameForLog + " " + e.getMessage() );
          }
    }

    ServiceConnection scConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

          public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
           bBindedBluetooth = false;
           Bluetooth = null;
          }

          public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName cnName, IBinder ibService) {
           bBindedBluetooth = true;
           LocalBinder mLocalBinder = (LocalBinder)ibService;
           Bluetooth = mLocalBinder.getServerInstance();

          }
    };   
}
```

And the problem goes here i don't have any idea how to fix this.

```
//Bluetooth.initService();
//Bluetooth.StartBluetoothConnection();
```

1. Run BluetoothService - works
2. bind BluetoothService - works
3. Run AsyncTask which must connect me to BluetoothDevice.
4. After 1-3 run MainActivity. - works

ad3. When i try to run Bluetooth.initService LOGCAT show me a:

An error occured while executing doInBackground();

in initService() i don't have a code (it is only for a test)

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to move your use of the `Bluetooth` object into `onServiceConnected()` because that's when the service is actually bound, which may or may not happen immediately after your call to `bindService()`

You could also bind to the service outside the `AsyncTask` in `onStart()` and start the `AsyncTask` from `onServiceConnected()`

Binding to the service uses a callback anyway and shouldn't be heavy on the UI thread.

Comment: Yes you're right but then i can't check in asyncTask is connection has been established. Sorry about my english;) I want to call method from binded Bluetooth object